# MSAL: Where is the starter Objective C example code?

Tags: objective-c, azure-ad-msal

When I register an app for MSAL the example code is only in Swift - is there Objective C example code hidden somewhere? The example app works fine for me but again it's written entirely in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc

In code samples, you have Swift and Objective-C code.